# Rest uniform interface for calculator app

Tags: django, rest, api, django-rest-framework

I am designing the rest api's for a basic calculator.

I need to know which is the best practise for defining interfaces?

```
/calc-service/add
/calc-service/sub
/cal-service/mul
```

2nd method

```
/calc-service/?params
```

Answer (score 0):

> I need to know which is the best practise for defining interfaces?

REST doesn't care what spelling you use for your resource identifiers.

Most computation queries are [safe](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.1), which is to say "read only", so you would normally plan to use [GET](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.1) semantics for the request, which in turn means that all of the client provided operands would appear in the target-uri

```
/calc-service/add/x=2/y=3
/calc-service/add?x=2&y=3
/calc-service?add&x=2&y=3
/calc-service/x=2/y=3/add
/calc-service/x=2/y=3?add
/calc-service?op=add&x=2&y=3
```

These are all *fine*.

Using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` parameters in your query string has the advantage that HTML clients already follow standards for form processing that produce URI with that shape from the data provided by the user in the form.

But any pattern that is easily expressed as a [URI Template](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6570) will be fine for clients that have the appropriate level of template processing available.

It could make sense in some cases to use coarse grained representations (think [DTO](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html)), with URI identifying specific sub elements

```
/calc-service/x=2/y=3#add
/calc-service/x=2/y=3#sub
/calc-service/x=2/y=3#mul
```